# unable to move a UIlabel in a xib programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I have created a UILabel in my interface builder (.XIB) and connect it to my .h file.  I have tried assigning a new value to its center to move it:

self.titleLabel.center = CGPointMake(100.f, 200.f);

However, this does not do anything.  Should I be moving the UILabel a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the center of the label should work. A couple of questions:

- Where are you making this call?
- Has the view been loaded at the time you make this call?

You can further troubleshoot this by setting a breakpoint at the line `self.titleLabel.center = CGPointMake(100.0f, 200.0f);` and checking if the `_titleLabel` variable is nil.